# ejabberd MAM does not work for MUC

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, muc

xep-0313 works for rosters, but does not work for room chat.
I can get archive message for the rosters, but I can not get archive message for the room, why?

```
<iq type='set' id='juliet1'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
       <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
           <value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value>
       </field>
      <field var='with'>
         <value>roomJid@conference.host</value>
      </field>
   </x>
  </query>
</iq>
```

The receive message is:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="test3@192.168.1.67" to="test3@192.168.1.67/iPhone" id="dHS0oejBDWHp”>
 <fin xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0" complete="true”>
      <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm”/>
 </fin>
 <no-copy xmlns="urn:xmpp:hints”/>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using ejabberd contributed module. However, a new official MAM module has been added to official ejabberd and it support latest version of MAM (0.4 as of today) and MUC archiving.

It has been released in [ejabberd 15.06](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-15-06/). You can can also get direct access to source from ejabberd Github repository. The module is here: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_mam.erl

Comment: I will test this in the next couple of days. I also write a module to hook the user_send_packet, in the hook, I store the MUC messages in SQL. Then provide a http API to request the MUC messages. From the client side point of view, I use the HTTP API to query the MUC history messages.

Comment: can I ask how do you use the http API to query the MUC history messages? I'm trying to get the history for a chat room by using this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828955/xmpp-query-archive-by-latest-messages) but it only seems to work for individual users

Comment: You should try latest master branch. It is much much improved and stick to the latest specifications.